# Dynamic Memory Allocation: What is the alternative for a two dimensional array when the rightmost dimension is variable?

Tags: c++, arrays, winapi, visual-c++, multidimensional-array

I am trying to develop a class to backup & restore console screen buffers. Here's my code in progress.

```
class CBuff
{
private:
    CONST WCHAR max_unit;
    HANDLE hnd;
    CHAR_INFO *stor_buff;
    COORD s_buff_sz;
    COORD d_buff_cod;
    SMALL_RECT read_region;

public:
    CBuff():max_unit(10)
    {}
    ~CBuff(){}

void Initiate(HANDLE hndl, SHORT buff_x, SHORT buff_y, SHORT buff_width, SHORT buff_height)
{
    hnd=hndl;
    stor_buff=new CHAR_INFO[buff_width*buff_height]();
    s_buff_sz.X=buff_width;
    s_buff_sz.Y=buff_height;
    d_buff_cod.X=0;
    d_buff_cod.Y=0;
    read_region.Left=0;
    read_region.Top=0;
    read_region.Right=buff_width-1;
    read_region.Bottom=buff_height-1;
}

int Backup()
{
    if(!ReadConsoleOutput(hnd,stor_buff,s_buff_sz,d_buff_cod,&read_region)) return -1;
    return 0;
}

int Restore()
{
    if(!WriteConsoleOutput(hnd,stor_buff,s_buff_sz,d_buff_cod,&read_region)) return -1;
    return 0;
}

int Backup_mp()
{/*incomplete*/}

int Restore_mp()
{/*incomplete*/}

};
```

It works with Backup() & Restore() fine. And then I tried to make another version of Backup, `Backup_mp(handle, backup_num)`, that will create multiple backups from different console buffer instances. I planned on converting last four variables in private space into array, so that a index value (backup_num) can be used for different backup point. An allocation like this

```
stor_buff=new CHAR_INFO[index][buff_width*buff_height]();
```

is not working.

What option do I have?

Also, can I use `CONST WCHAR max_unit` as the parameter for an array like `s_buff_sz[max_unit]`  ?

Answer (score 1):

You're using C++, so make use of it: Use std::vector.

```
//Declaration of your buffers:
std::vector< std::vector<CHAR_INFO> > store_buffers;

//Append a new buffer entry:
store_buffers.push_back( std::vector<CHAR_INFO>( buff_width * buff_height ) );

// Pass buffer with index index to WinAPI functions:
..., store_buffers[index].data(), s_buff_sz, ...
```

If using C++11, you can use std::array for the fixed sized dimension (instead of std::vector, which is variable), but that's not critical.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am a beginner and still not very much clear about STL. But, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

To allocate a two-dimensional array in heap (using `new`), you need to allocate the pointers first, and then the arrays. Example:

```
stor_buff = new CHAR_INFO* [buff_height]; // Allocate rows (pointers
for(int index = 0; index < buff_height; ++index)
   stor_buff[index] = new CHAR_INFO[buff_width];
```

And use them directly, as if `store_buff` is 2D array. For deallocation, you need to delete the arrays (i.e. individual rows) first, and then the row-pointer.

```
  for(int index = 0; index < buff_height; ++index)
        delete []stor_buff[index];   // NOTICE the syntax

    delete []stor_buff;
```

Or, you may have a single-dimensional array, use it as 2D. For this you need to do `(row,col)` calculation to get the desired element.

You may also use `vector` (or `vector` of `vector`), to get the same. But I suggest you to play with native pointers, unless you get accustomed with pointers!